# Expressing a solid in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

I am trying to solve the following question:

> The volume of the solid $E$ can be represented as
> $$\int_{-3}^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} 3 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2} dydx$$
> Describe the solid in spherical coordinates.

I graphed the solid and it looks like this:

[image]

So clearly $0 \le \theta \le \pi$ and $0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}.$ Also, for each $(\theta, \phi)$ the value of $\rho$ ranges from $0$ until the surface of the cone. The cone is $z = 3-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Using the substitutions
\begin{align*}
x &= \rho \cos \theta \sin \phi\\
y &= \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi\\
z &= \rho \cos \phi
\end{align*}
we get
\begin{align*}
\rho \cos \phi &= 3 - \sqrt{\rho^2 \sin^2 \phi}\\
\rho &= \frac {3}{\cos \phi + \sin \phi}
\end{align*}
So my answer is
$$E_{\text{spherical}} = \{(\rho, \theta, \phi)| 0 \le \theta \le \pi, 0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 \le \rho \le \frac {3}{\cos \phi + \sin \phi} \}$$
However, the correct answer is
$$E_{\text{spherical}} = \{(\rho, \theta, \phi)| 0 \le \theta \le \pi, 0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{4}, 0 \le \rho \le 3 \csc\phi \}$$

Did I make any mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is correct. See here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zpbns0uzvl

Comment: @MatthewPilling Ahh yes thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solid is half of an inverted cone with vertex at $(0, 0, 3)$ and above $z = 0$.

Equation of the surface of the cone is $ ~\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 3 - z$

That translates to $ \rho \sin\phi = 3 - \rho \cos\phi \implies \rho = \frac{3}{\cos\phi + \sin\phi}$

Please note that $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$ as we are above $z = 0$.

Also given bounds of $x$ and $y$, you can see that the projection of the solid in xy-plane is in the first and the second quadrant. That leads to $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

$E_{\text{spherical}} = \{(\rho, \theta, \phi)| 0 \le \rho \le \frac{3}{ \cos\phi + \sin\phi}, 0 \le \theta \le \pi, 0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2} \}$

But to evaluate the volume, it is easier to use $ ~ x = \rho \cos\theta\sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = 3 - \rho \cos\phi$

That translates the cone to $ ~ \phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$

$\rho$ is bound by the plane $z = 3 - \rho \cos\phi = 0 \implies \rho = 3 \sec\phi$

So the integral to find volume in spherical coordinates should be,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{3\sec\phi} ~ \rho^2 \sin\phi ~ d\rho ~ d\phi ~ d\theta$

Comment: The OP did not ask about the volume or the integral that would express it... It was about describing the region in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Oh wow this makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: @PierreCarre From the bounds on the integral I can see the region.

Comment: @PierreCarre sure I would add that too

Comment: @user56202 You could see the region right from the start! The bounds do not correspond to the region,  although it gives you the correct value for the volume.

Comment: @PierreCarre Hmm by "the bounds do not correspond to the region" are you saying that $\{(\rho, \theta, \phi)| 0 \le \theta \le \pi, 0 \le \phi \le \pi/4, 0 \le \rho \le 3 \sec \phi \}$ does not get mapped bijectively onto the original region, under the transformation provided by Math Lover?

Comment: @user56202 it does map but it is not the solid described in the original coordinate system

Comment: @user56202 I'm saying that the integral here presented corresponds to another cone... but the volume is the same.

Comment: @PierreCarre Sorry, I'm a little slow. So you are saying that under the standard spherical coordinate transformation (the one I wrote down), the image of the solid presented in the integral is a different cone than the original cone?

Comment: @user56202 Yes, this cone is "up-side-down" with respect to the original one, with its vertex at $(0,0,0)$. But this answer is correct... The description of the region is correct, and the integral yields the correct value.

Comment: @user56202 look at it this way, $\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\phi = \frac{3\pi}{4}$ are cones that have vertex at $(0, 0, 0)$ and open up and open down respectively.

Comment: @PierreCarre, Math Lover Thanks, I understand now. I just didn't realize you were pushing forward with the standard transformation, while pulling back with the modified transformation. Even thought I think the question is wrong and I will email the professor, it is nice to see that the answer has an interpretation that makes SOME sense, and it is not utter nonsense.

Comment: @user56202 The question is ambiguous right from the start (even though  we can get the intention)... Any expression that can be given for a volume does not determine the region. The cone used by MathLover has the same volume and would also be a correct answer.

Comment: @PierreCarre Oh that's very interesting, I never thought about it that way.

Comment: @user56202 The ambiguity arises because of the integration. What we see here is that it's easier to do the integration under a change of coordinates that isn't just the standard change from Cartesian to spherical: it's a change to spherical coordinates whose center is at the vertex of the cone and whose axis is in a direction opposite the $z$ axis. But IMHO that is not at all how the question was posed to you and your answer is the correct one for the question as asked.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you for your comment. I am happy I learned this new technique of doing shifted cylindrical coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" answer does not seem to be correct, at least not according to the change of variable you present ($\phi = 0$ for points in the $z$ axis). It should be:

$$
\{(\theta, \phi, \rho): 0\leq \theta \leq \pi, 0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 \leq \rho \leq \frac{3}{\cos \phi+ \sin \phi} \},
$$

as you mention. So, your solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks. But why is $\phi$ bounded below by $\pi/4$? Our solid contains points on the $z$ axis, which have a $\phi$ of $0$.

Comment: @user56202 My bad! I'll correct!